# how to retrieve multiple values returned by select statement in trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, subquery

I have Created the following trigger in phpmyadmin.

```
delimiter |
create trigger active after insert on event
for each row
begin
declare n int;
set n = (select follower_id from follow where circle_id=new.circle_id);
insert into activity (uid, performed_activity_id,activity_type_id) values(new.uid,new.event_id,'1');
insert into notification (sender_id,receiver_id,message)values (new.uid,n,new.title);
end;
|
```

I am getting problem over here is that the select statement retures more the one value.

`ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

how to fetch multiple values from select statement and how to pass them to insert statemant.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is on this line,

```
set n = (select follower_id from follow where circle_id=new.circle_id);
```

The variable can only hold one value. If the result of the query is *null* or one value then it's fine, otherwise it will throw an error message that the select query returns multiple value.

But it can be resolve by adding `LIMIT`, eg

```
set n = (select follower_id from follow where circle_id=new.circle_id LIMIT 1);
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
delimiter |
create trigger active after insert on event
for each row
begin

    insert into activity (uid, performed_activity_id, activity_type_id) 
    values (new.uid, new.event_id, '1');

    insert into notification (sender_id, receiver_id, message)
    select new.uid, follower_id, new.title
    from   follow 
    where  circle_id=new.circle_id;

end |
delimiter ;
```

Comment: but i want all the values of follower_id and pass them to notification